# The type of namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces

I have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using BLL;

namespace LicenseManager.Controllers
{
    public class ValidationController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Default()
        {
            return View("Default");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ClearInstallation(FormCollection form)
        {
            var jr = new JsonResult();
            try
            {
                var licMgr = new BLL.LicManager();
                licMgr.ClearInstall(form["regKey"], form["checkKey"]);

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                jr = Json(new { success = "false", error = exc.Message });
            }

            return jr;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to rebuild or debug I receive the error: `The type of namespace name 'BLL' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I can see that it is referenced:

[image]

The intellisense works, and I don't have any errors, until I try to rebuild or compile. I know it exists, and it finds it for intellisense purposes, so why won't it allow me to rebuild or compile?

I have tried:

- cleaning the solution
- rebuilding
- clearing the reference and re-adding it

What else can I try?

**UPDATE**
If you get this error, make sure you read the output. It contained the solution for me.

Comment: I had a similar problem when the referenced project was using a different .net framework. Have you confirmed that they match?
You can verify/change the framework in properties/application/target framework

Comment: They were different and it fixed my issue. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem when the referenced project was using a different .net framework. Make sure the project you are building and the project you have referenced are using the same framework.

You can verify/change the framework in properties/application/target framework

Comment: I should have investigated a bit closer. Turns out the Output pane explained that the target framework didn't match.

Comment: Did you get a warning?

Comment: If by warning you mean there error listed, yes. Otherwise, it just gave the error.  However, in the details in Output, it told me the target framework for BLL didn't match the solution's target.

Comment: I've had this issue with Nuget packages too. Upgrading the .NET version of the project and reinstalling the Nuget package fixed it.